# How can I implement an interface and inherit from a base class?

Tags: c#, .net

The below is not valid-

```
public partial class form1 : Form : ICloneable
```

Is there a simple way to use ICloneable on a form class?

Comment: You could try `:Form, ICloneable` but that's only the beginning... I don't think you should clone Forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually right way is separate by comma:

```
public partial class form1 : Form, ICloneable
```